# Django not auto populating current user foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm inserting entries into my database from the front end but the current logged in user foreign key is not populating. It get's entered as null.

here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class WordsAndPhrases (models.Model):
    word_or_phrase = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.word_or_phrase
```

here is my views.py code snippet.

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        wordOrPhrase = request.POST['word-or-phrase']
        currentUser = request.user
        print(currentUser)
        newEntry = WordsAndPhrases(word_or_phrase = wordOrPhrase)
        addedBy = WordsAndPhrases(added_by = currentUser)
        newEntry.save()

    return render(request, 'display_words_phrases_app/upload.html')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an id key in your model

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two entry objects. When you create a new object, you should insert both `word_or_phrase` and `added_by` like this:

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    wordOrPhrase = request.POST['word-or-phrase']
    currentUser = request.user
    print(currentUser)
    newEntry = WordsAndPhrases(word_or_phrase = wordOrPhrase, added_by = currentUser)
    newEntry.save()

return render(request, 'display_words_phrases_app/upload.html')
```

Your `addedBy` object was useless.